# Cryptic Linq to Entities message

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I get the following message:

{"Entities in 'Entities.ApprovalRequests' participate in the 'FK_ApprovalRequest_Audit' relationship. 0 related 'Audit' were found. 1 'Audit' is expected."}

I'm stumped, does anyone know what to make of it?

My EDMX had the FK and is correct, yet every time I get this message.

How one would go to debug this, would be most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably tried to persist an entity of type `ApprovalRequests` with no associated entity of type `Audit` while your entity model specifies that each `ApprovalRequests` must have (at least) one `Audit`.